# prevent page jumping to anchor target

Tags: html, css

I have a slider looks like this:

[image]

the bottom buttons are anchors like this `<a href="#slide-1">1</a>`.

and this is my slider (and anchors) css code:

```css
#slider {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#slider img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
#slider-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: calc(-10vw - 20px); /* I know I can use relative or absoulute positioning. but problem is not here */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#slider-buttons a {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

the problem is in this state:

[image]

> When I click on an anchor (in this state), the page jumps to the top of picture.

I can't use javascript, in this case.

Comment: Please post as a [mcve]

Comment: I think that you need at least inline JS to achieve that with your HTML syntax.

Comment: That's the default behaviour of anchors. You can only disable this via javascript.